# how to find the max number of days for each city?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

As you see below, there are many cities and days(period of raining days). 
I want to find the `max` days even if days are the same. 
For example if maximum days are 3 and there are two 3 days, then i want to print out two rows.

Possible outputs would be:

```
Auckland     2013-11-30 2013-11-30 5
Christchurch 2013-11-10 2013-11-50 4
```

If there are only 5 cities, there might be 5 rows to 10 rows depending on the same value of days.

I want to use `SELECT`, `IF` or `CASE`, `MAX` or `Count` functions, as this part is one of the complete, complex code.

Thank you.

[image]

SQL Version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

this is the example data:

```
 create  TABLE practice10 (
    station VARCHAR(50),
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    days INT,
   )

   INSERT INTO practice10 values ('Auckland','2013-10-5','2013-10-10', 5),
   ('Auckland','2013-10-15','2013-10-17', 2),
   ('Auckland','2013-10-20','2013-10-23', 3),
   ('Manchester','2015-9-1','2013-9-4', 3),
   ('Manchester','2013-10-3','2013-10-3', 0),
   ('Manchester','2013-10-20','2013-10-29', 9);
```

Comment: Please add your sample data as text in your question and not a screenshot, as we cannot copy and paste from this to help answer your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seem like a simple use of `MAX`.

Comment: If I use max function, it shows errors saying "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 276
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: That's not the fault of the `MAX` that's because you're trying to put an `ORDER BY` clause in a `VIEW`. The error is telling you the problem; don't put an `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW`.

Comment: That's why I am stuck. I extracted consecutive days from raw data and have to read line by line to use cursor for practice purpose. But, it seems like the only way is to process the data again and read a few lines using while @@fetch ==0. To do that, I need to use MAX, which is not allowed in the VIEW. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order days using `dense_rank()`. Then use `top 1` to get days with highest values

```
select
    top 1 with ties *
from
    myTable
order by dense_rank() over (partition by station order by days desc)
```

Comment: The problem is when there are the same values of same days. This could be two or three lines.

Comment: `Dense_rank` will return all those rows. But if you want to get only one row then use `row_number`

Comment: Seems like I can find the values i want thanks to you. i will let you know if i have another problems coming up!. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked the result backwards from data. It seems alright. Thanks to you. I really appreciate it. I pondered on many days and you gave me good insight and new concepts. Thank you.

Comment: @JayceLila, glad to help!